# Erro no emulador do android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-xml

Ao tentar testar o código no emulador aparece o seguinte erro:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                  Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 14353
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~osDNAnNtB7hgTGO5EmU8Yg==/com.example.myapplication-_KqFrVlGS3dEe3sb64-ylw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~osDNAnNtB7hgTGO5EmU8Yg==/com.example.myapplication-_KqFrVlGS3dEe3sb64-ylw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~osDNAnNtB7hgTGO5EmU8Yg==/com.example.myapplication-_KqFrVlGS3dEe3sb64-ylw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~osDNAnNtB7hgTGO5EmU8Yg==/com.example.myapplication-_KqFrVlGS3dEe3sb64-ylw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
```

[<sup>Imagem mostrando o erro</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpr8S.png)

Segue os códigos abaixo: **acivity_login.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="80px"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdtftech"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:text="DTF Tech"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="80px" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:text="Usuário"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSenha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:text="Senha"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#007bff"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40px" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCadastrese"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#007bff"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:paddingTop="50px"
        android:text="Cadastre-se" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Acesso.java**

```
[package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Acesso extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btLogin, btCadastrese;
    private Thread view;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogin);
        btLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        btCadastrese = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCadastrese);
        btCadastrese.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (view.getId()==R.id.btLogin) {
            Intent intencao = new Intent(this, Acesso.class);
            startActivity(intencao);

        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btCadastrese) {
            Intent intencao = new Intent(this, cadastrese.class);
            startActivity(intencao);


        }
    }
}
```

**activity_cadastrese.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblmsg1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNomeCad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblmsg2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-mail:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmailCad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblmsg3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Senha:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSenhaCad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblmsg4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirma Senha:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtConfSenhaCad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCadastrar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#007bff"
        android:text="Cadastrar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVoltar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#e3164a"
        android:text="Voltar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**cadastrese.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class cadastrese extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnCadastrar;
    Button btnVoltar;

    EditText txtNomeCad, txtEmailCad, txtSenhaCad, txtConfSenhaCad;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnVoltar) {

            Intent intencao = new Intent(this, Acesso.class);
            startActivity(intencao);

        } 
    }}
```

Comment: Icaro, Eu fiz as alteracoes abaixo e paraou de apresentar esse erro, o aplicativo abriu as duas telas, bastando colocar a oncreate na outra acitivy

Comment: Em Acesso.java o codigo view.getId()==R.id.btLogin está errado tbm deve ser: codigo v.getId()==R.id.btLogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei aqui e funcionou:

basta ir no projeto ao lado da janela e substituir tudo que esta em "app/build.gradle (:app)" por:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 48
        versionName "4.8"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


}
```

depois manda Sync (sincronizar) o projeto que vai funcionar.

Não se esqueça de colocar o nome correto do projeto no AndroidManifest.xml

*outra coisa é que está faltando o comando:
< / LinearLayout >

no final do arquivo activity_login.xml